# How to play an audio when home button clicked in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

Now am developing an application in which the application will play the audio automatically when the home button is tapped (when entering the background mode), below is my code i've used. it works perfectly in simulator but not working in any of the devices (iPhone, iPad, iPod). please guide me to go further...

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {   
        AVAudioSession * session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
                [session setDelegate: self]; 
                [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
                [session setActive:YES error:nil];

                NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], soundName]];    
                AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
                audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
                [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
                [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
                [audioPlayer play];
            }


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        NSAssert(backgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);
        backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
    }





 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, when the app is going into the background audio is muted thus the sound you play will nog be heard.

And this will be very annoying and should just not be done, also the simulator reacts differently than then a real iOS device.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-my-phone-security-system/id478749950?mt=8 .  in this app theyuse that thing please check it out....

Answer (score 0):

An app can only play audio that has been started before entering background mode.  Note that an app can play silent audio, but Apple has rejected apps that play a lot of silence.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-my-phone-security-system/id478749950?mt=8 .  in this app theyuse that thing please check it out....